# Disable HTML input without disabling mouse events

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to disable an HTML input while keeping mouse events?

I know that `disabled="disabled"` also stops events from being evaluated. What I need to do is disable clicking on the input element, but still recognize the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events (for switching background images).

Note that I am not searching for a workaround like making it look disabled with CSS or something like that. I want to actually make it impossible to be clicked (like clicking on an image), but I can NOT just use an image instead.

Comment: You have the `readonly=true` property for that

Comment: Be careful with the `true` on boolean attributes. This might imply that there is a `readonly="false"`. The convention is to write the name as value, like `readonly="readonly"`.

Answer (score 5):

Readonly?

```
 <input readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

You can preserve mouse events, but will be impossible to fill with keyboard.

Comment: I have tried that before. Unfortunately, while changing a value becomes impossible this way, it can still be submitted. Like I said, I am using a background image, which I am swapping on mouseover. The readonly approach would work for textfields, but not for buttons, images and others. My problem is not being able to change the value, but being able to click and submit.

Comment: But what did you need? It's a weird explanation. You need to swap a background image, and for this you use inputs? I don't understand nothing with your last comment. If you don't need to be submitted there are three ways: 1) Don't insert an input inside a form. 2) Don't insert an input. 3) Make it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem by using `css`

```html
<input type="text" name="">
```

```css
input{

 pointer-events: none;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand, you want that clicking on an input field, you do not want the user to be able to write in it, with the field still not disabled
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "#input_field" ).on('focus',function(){
    $( this ).blur() 
  });
});
```

Comment: The exact opposite is the case.

Comment: If you want to disable the click event: $( "#input_field" ).click( function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })

Comment: This only works on some elements. I made a class `input_noclick` and assigned it to some inputs (all of type image), but on some the click is still recognized, while on some it is ignored.

Comment: This can happen ONLY if you added some event listener after it.